# css sub menu acting up in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-lists, submenu

i have manually added a menu to my wordpress header.php theme file
everything looks great when i use single ul but if i use the sub-menu feature of WP and add move items under a single menu link, a weird result turns out which you can see here.
[image: result]

The result i am looking for is adding a :hover effect which will only then show the sub-menu items, but first thing the items should get in line, under the right li item (Jobs -> Job Seekers & Job Offers)

Why do i get the unexpected 521px sub-menu width and how do i solve my predicament

```
<li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-103"><a href="http://ldpolishing.com/_dev/jobs/job-offers/">Jobs</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-101"><a href="http://ldpolishing.com/_dev/jobs/job-seekers/">Job Seekers</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-102" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-102"><a href="http://ldpolishing.com/_dev/jobs/job-offers/">Job Offers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

[Link to the page](http://ldpolishing.com/_dev/)
Thank you

Comment: There is absolutely no way of knowing without seeing the CSS applied to your menu.  I'd advise posting a working example if you want people to debug this.

Comment: added the link to the page

Comment: Make it a JSFiddle please.

Comment: can't do that since it is a wordpress site, there is too much to consider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is simple.  You can set your parent `<li>` tag to have a `position: relative;`, then you can set the `.sub-menu` to be `position: absolute;` and set to the `left: 0;` so it lines up to the left of your `<li>`.

Then you can hide the sub-menu and display it when you hover over the li.

Try this CSS:

```
#top .menu li {
   position: relative;
}

#top .menu .sub-menu {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   text-align: left;
   margin:0;
   width: 150px;
}

#top .menu .sub-menu .li {
   padding:0;
}

#top .menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: i had to make a lot of modifications but the idea was the same
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give this jQuery-based menu script that I built a try?  It uses a combination of CSS and jQuery to make a keyboard-accessible horizontal menu and supports up to five levels of navigation.  Additionally it has context highlighting/dimming, showing your path as you traverse through the menu:

http://code.google.com/p/keyboard-accessible-jquery-menu/

You can see a demo of it in action here:

http://designbymichael.com/dev/top-menu/demo/

As to your source code, you've got a few problems going on — your parent LI tag should have the attribute position: relative to give your submenu's a starting place to launch from.  Your submenu then should have position: absolute and then position accordingly off the parent navigation.  I'd also recommend using margin-right instead of padding-right for your menu spacing, since you're attempting to put a margin space between your menu items and not such extreme padding only on one side of each item.

As @Ennui pointed out, if you would make this a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net) you'd allow us to branch your copy off, make edits, and show you what we came up with.

That said, save yourself a little time and use a pre-built menu script instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.  By no means, don't feel like you have to use mine — there are hundreds of scripts out there to choose from.